# Elementary reference on Support Vector Machines

Tags: computer-science, machine-learning, bayesian, data-mining

I am having difficulties in reading the book *Support vector mathine* by Ingo Steinwart with some notations and mathematical terms . Can you please  recommend  a prerequisite book or online course by any universities which followed the book  for that?

Answer (score 0):

I really like this [tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/zoya/www/SVM.pdf) which provides a very good overview. Also this [recitation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ik7E7r2a1h8&t=986s) is very well done.

I would then move on to [Bishop](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) and use [Boyd and Vanderbenghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) as a reference for convex optimisation.